# How to merge two arrays in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays like below.

```
A = [{fruit: apple, number:4 }, {fruit: pear, number: 3}]
B = [{qual: good}, {qual: bad}]
```

And My goal is getting an array like below.

```
C = [{fruit: apple, number:4, qual: good }, {fruit: pear, number: 3, qual: bad}]
```

The length of A, B is same. I can make this using 'for loop'. But how can I make it using 'some array methods' like 'concat' or 'map'?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
let A = [{fruit: 'apple', number:4 }, {fruit: 'pear', number: 3}]
let B = [{qual: 'good'}, {qual: 'bad'}]

let C = A.map((value, index) => ({ ...value,  ...B[index] }))

console.log(C)
```

Index is used to access respective value from second array, and merged into a single object using spread syntax

Comment: How is index referring to respective value from the second array?

Comment: @Bhawan array are list like objects, and can be accessed using index, [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Using `for` loop:

```js
let array1 = [{ fruit: "apple", number: 4 }, { fruit: "pear", number: 3 }]
let array2 = [{ qual: "good" }, { qual: "bad" }]
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  array1[i].qual = array2[i].qual;
}
console.log(array1)
```

Using `map`:

```js
let array1 = [{fruit: 'apple', number:4 }, {fruit: 'pear', number: 3}]
let array2 = [{qual: 'good'}, {qual: 'bad'}]

let C = array1.map((value, index) => {
  return {
    fruit: value.fruit,
    number: value.number,
    qual: array2[index].qual
  }
})
console.log(C)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not provided the condition to merge, I am assuming it is index based, mean first object from second array will go to first object in first array and so on. If that is the case you can use `map` which will create a new array. In `map` callback return a object with required keys and values

```js
let a = [{
  fruit: 'apple',
  number: 4
}, {
  fruit: 'pear',
  number: 3
}]
let b = [{
  qual: 'good'
}, {
  qual: 'bad'
}]

let newArray = a.map((item, index) => {

  return {
    fruit: item.fruit,
    number: item.number,
    qual: b[index].qual
  }
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be slightly faster than the top answer but it's more code and top answer is much more straightforward.

```js
const a = [{ fruit: "apple", number: 4 }, { fruit: "pear", number: 3 }];
const b = [{ qual: "good" }, { qual: "bad" }];
const c = [];

a.forEach((fruit, index) => {
    const newFruit = { ...fruit, ...b[index]}
    c.push(newFruit)
});

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use use the spread operator directly 
let A = [{fruit: 'apple', number:4 }, {fruit: 'pear', number: 3}]
let B = [{qual: 'good'}, {qual: 'bad'}]

let C = [...A, ...B]

console.log(C);

Answer (score 0):

you can use array.concat method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to join two arrays.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
  var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
  var children = hege.concat(stale); 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = children;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```